# dynamically join multiple tables in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

So i have a table like this

[image]

as you can see, the existing tables have almost similar names and each `table` has the same `column` structure and each table only have data for one month, example `air_message2021_01` only have data from January, `air_message2021_02` only have data from February etc.

on my project it is required to search data by `JOIN` some existing tables but dynamically like this.

[image]

in the picture you can see there is aircraft id field, year, from date containt month and date field, to date containt month and date field, from time field and to time field.

because each table only has data for 1 month and the user can search for data with a time span of 6 months, I have to dynamically merge the tables because the system will not know which time range the user will be looking for.

**Example**

**User1** search data aircraft ID **BTK7369** from **2021-01-12** to **2021-04-20**

it mean i have to join `air_message2021_01`, `air_message2021_02`, `air_message2021_03` and `air_message2021_04`

**User2** search data aircarft ID **BTK7552** from **2021-05-27** to **2021-08-09**

it mean i have to join `air_message2021_05`, `air_message2021_06`, `air_message2021_07` and `air_message2021_08`

How to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us your attempted query and run `SELECT version();` to check MySQL version.

Comment: In mysql (5.7.33) something like this ```SELECT * FROM `air_message2021_03` JOIN air_message2021_04 ON air_message2021_03.type7a = air_message2021_04.type7a WHERE air_message2021_03.type7a = 'KAL627' BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-04-23';```

in laravel i have not found the solution.

Comment: What you want to do in "Laravel" is not how you would do it in laravel. dont create a hacky mess. either refactor it into one table or do your raw query command.

Comment: The MySQL query is not really "dynamic" unless you're generating the query using something else like a prepared statement based on the date range provided from the front end. Also, are you sure that you need to `JOIN` instead of `UNION`? If one of the table that you join doesn't have that data (`type7a = 'KAL627'`), it won't return any result.

Comment: @FanoFN what I need is to search for data according to the ```aircraft id``` and the specified time range, so it's actually not too problematic to use ```JOIN``` or ```UNION``` as long as the data sought is according to the user's wishes.

Comment: I'll post something that you might be able to use in MySQL and with few tests. I can't really suggest anything as to how you will implement that in Laravel though because I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @MichaelMano I also thought the same thing.
but that's not what the user asked me to do. :(

Comment: . [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Comment: See this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b76d0fdcdf7661b040e0f960017cfc01 @Habinata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model of `air_message*` tables you can declare same as :

```
class AirMessageRead extends Model
{
    /**
     * Name base table
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseTable = 'air_message';

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = '';

    /**
     * For Read.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $exists = true;

    /**
     * AirMessageRead constructor.
     *
     * @param int $time
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($time)
    {
        $this->table = $this->getTableName($time);
    }

    /**
     * Get table name
     *
     * @param int $time
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTableName($time)
    {
        return $this->baseTable . $time;
    }
}
```

On `service` you convert range date to array () and onion :

`use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;`

```
private function getTimeRange($start, $end)
{
    foreach (CarbonPeriod::create($start, '1 month', $end) as $month) {
        $months[] = $month->format('Y_m');
    }
    return $months;
}

private function getTablesForQuery($start, $end)
{
    $months = $this->getTimeRange($start, $end);
    $mergeTables = array_map(fn($month) => new AirMessageRead($month), $months);
    foreach ($mergeTables as $table) {
        if (isset($query)) {
            $query = $query->union($table);
        } else {
            $query = $table;
        }
    }
    return $query
}
```

and get onion tables :

```
// $query is model for you
$model = $this->getTablesForQuery('2021-01-12', '2021-04-20');
```

**You can add function for checking exist table on Model**